# Issue with Vue js when passing v-model as array to components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vuejs and got stuck with this issue.
Link to code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cdq8xu9t/

Js

```
Vue.component('jk',{
    props:['value'],
template:`
    <div v-for="val in value">
        <input type="text" v-bind:value="val.a" v-on:input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)">
        <input type="text" v-bind:value="val.b" v-on:input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)">
    </div>
`
});

new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    add:[{
        a:'apple',
    b:'orange'
    }]
}
})
```

Html

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <jk v-model="add"></jk>
</div>
```

The issue is as follows.
The components are generated but when i change the values, something goes wrong.

I used the vue-js addon in chrome and found that 
when i change the values in the input field, the add object becomes a string.
Can anyone suggest a fix. Please.

Comment: What do you want to do with this code? Not so detailed.

Comment: @renato Manalili: Have you tried the jsfiddle link and tried changing the input fields value.

Comment: @RenatoManalili: What i actually want is that:
I want to update the add array values from the component jk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in passing props.

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <jk :value="add"></jk>
</div>
```

And you need to add an unqiue `key` for each item when using `v-for`.

```
    <div
      v-for="val in value"
      :key="val.id" // recommended :)
    >
        <input type="text" v-bind:value="val.a" v-on:input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)">
        <input type="text" v-bind:value="val.b" v-on:input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)">
    </div>
```

Sometimes devs use `index` as `key`, but it is not recommended.

```
    <div
      v-for="(val, index) in value"
      :key="index" // not recommended :(
    >
```

Here is the full [code](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonioCollins/hpr3L4xk/3/).

Comment: but add variable in the instance doesn't seem to updating when changes are made in the input fields. There seems to be no two way binding happening as the above code.

Comment: thank you, I seem to found an alternative method by tweaking with the code. Can you please tell me if it is wrong or right. It seems to work. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s6n3uyjr/

Comment: Maybe, in your codes, two way binding is not happening when you update the values.

Comment: i verified with vue addon in chrome. seems to updating the root variables. Is it some bug?

Comment: I can be mutating but not two-way binding. Because you pass them as object array.

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot For more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982016/vuejs-how-to-mutate-an-object-thats-passed-as-a-prop

Comment: By any chance, do you know who to pass the objects via sync in vue js. Fiddle here ** https://jsfiddle.net/tmwbkL40/ **